# Не могу установить библиотеку TA Lib

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку пайтон ta lib,но выдаёт ошибку :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: По инструкции (https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/) все делали?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла настройка среды выполнения. Вот часть инструкции с https://xn-----6kcjd7aa0cfnmaec4e.xn--p1ai/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-talib-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81-10/

1. Откройте Панель управления и найдите раздел Система и безопасность. Найдите раздел Система. Нажмите Дополнительные параметры и перейдите во вкладку Дополнительно.
2. Нажмите Переменные среды.
   В разделе Переменные среды пользователя нажмите Создать.
   В поле Имя переменной введите "TA-LIB", а в поле Значение переменной вставьте путь к папке TA-LIB (туда, где вы распаковали архив со скачанной библиотекой), например "С:ta-lib"/
   3.Нажмите ОК во всех открытых окнах.